# Ruby: Secure select IN and validation in controller vs model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, validation

Normally validation logic should go in the model and not the controller... but I have a situation where I get a JSON POST request that gives me a list of item numbers where each number should be a PK into a DB table.

I want to check each PK exists, but don't want to do *n* `SELECT` queries, just 1 query using `SELECT ... IN (x,y,...)`, using the ActiveRecord `.where(id: idsThatShouldBeInDb)`, `idsThatShouldBeInDb` being an array of integers.

I have tried the following very noddy little test to check for safety

```
Item.where(id: [1,2,3,'a', nil, '']).count
```

This produces, in the console window for the server:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM "items" 
WHERE (("items"."id" IN (1, 2, 3, 0, 0) OR "trip_items"."id" IS NULL))
```

What I was hoping is that a validation exception would be thrown for the non-integer parameters so that essentially the model is validating the input data.

It seems to me that when I receive data as a JSON string and I parse it into a hash using `JSON.parse` that I must then check that

1. The hash contains all the relevant keys because if a key doesn't exist it would return `nil` and create the insecure and incorrect `IS NULL` in the above
2. Must check that the key value is an integer to avoid selecting an `item` with ID 0 by mistake.

So it is the controller, not the model, that is doing the validation (or at least a portion of it). I should point out I'm not being lazy... quite happy to validation code in the controller, I was just thinking that this does tend to distribute the validation task across two modules rather than it being nicely contained in the model...

From a Ruby, or generally even a MVC perspective, what's the best way to validate the received JSON data? I'd go for all-validation-in-model, but it seems the controller, in this case must do some of it's own validation. Is there a better way? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do as below:

```
[1] pry(main)> [1,2,3,'a', nil, ''].map(&:to_int)
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_int' for "a":String
from (pry):1:in `map'
```

`to_int` would raise an exception if it is called on a non Integer object, so if you want to validate if the pks are integers without hitting the DB, this is your best choice, hence you leave the Model with its DB related activities

Comment: Just an idea: `[1,2,3,'a', nil, ''].reject { |x| x.to_int && false rescue true }`

Comment: But the most efficient way: `[1,2,3,'a', nil, ''].reject { |x| !x.is_a?(Numeric) }` or, if you want only integers, replace Numeric with Fixnum.

Comment: @GaborGarami the OP wants some "validation exception would be thrown for the non-integer parameters", it is left to him to handle the exception how it pleases him

Answer (score 0):

Item.find([1,2,3,'a', nil, '']) will raise an exception if one of the keys is not in primary keys (with the exception of nil). Assuming you trust your database primary keys, I'd do something like...

```
begin
  raise if !pks.all?(&:present?)
  Item.find pks
rescue
end
```

Comment: however testing it now - it doesn't raise an exception if an item is nil. Updating my response.

Comment: ok, thanks for the suggestion. the `nil` detection is pretty important

Answer (score 0):

To be sure, it appears that you want to validate that the list of id's being passed are legitimate integers (not 0, negative, character, or `nil`).  A simple:

```
 myList.any?{|i| i.to_i <= 0}
```

should suffice to detect this (although it won't account for floats if that is a real concern).  You can add this as a helper module method (extending ActiveSupport::Concern) and include this module in any of your models or controllers where this detection would be warranted.

That aside, I don't think this is validation as much as it is *sanitization* of primitive user input.  Such a concern is quite welcome in a controller in my opinion (although a module may be a better fit as mentioned above).  This is in comparison to model validation, which checks that a model's behavior, state, and persistence are what we expect them to be.

In addition, I'm not sure exactly what you want to accomplish by doing this sanitization check.  It would appear that a consumer would know that id's should be positive integers, so any missing records shouldn't be unexpected.  Passing 0 or NULL to a search on primary key won't yield any results, and doesn't appear to open any security hole to me.  But maybe I'm being naive... can you clarify precisely what your concerns are here?  Or is it that you simply want to make the user aware of their poorly formed query?